# Where did the code in apk file go after installed from Market?

Tags: android

This is a very interesting thing. I have an APK file, com.company.app.apk. When installed to an emulator by using Eclipse, by using the following code to get the apk's file name:

```
String fileName = activity.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo(
    activity.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_META_DATA).publicSourceDir;
```

I get a pathname like this `com.company.app-1.apk`. The file size is the same as the apk file I built.

Now when I publish this app to Market, and install it to a real device (Android 2.3), the same code returned a pathname like this: `com.company.app-2.zip`. Note that the file extension has changed to .zip and, most importantly, the file size is significantly smaller than the original size.

Now if I transfer these two files to my PC and use WinZip to open them, I found one really interesting thing:

The one installed on emulator by Eclipse has exactly the same stuff as I expected. Namely: the code ('com' folder), the resource ('res' folder), the signature ('META-INF' folder), the assets ('assets' folder), and the manifest file (AndroidManifest.xml). However, the one installed on a real device by Market has only two parts: the resource, and the manifest file.

**Question:** I think when installed from Market, the .apk file is split into two (or more) files. One file is pointed to by `ApplicationInfo.publicSourceDir`, which contains only the resource. How can I get the pathname to the other file(s)?

**ADDED:** I have two versions of the same app, one is paid using Google's Vendor Licensing Service, the other is free. The above mentioned phenomenon happens only to the paid version. Why?

**Correction:** When I said the 'com' folder exists in the installed apk file in the first case, I should be more clear. The code per se, the *.java files, are not in the 'com' folder. As a matter of fact, the 'com' folder contains only a few garbage files that were inadvertently left there during the build process. If not for those garbage files, I don't think the 'com' folder would be there in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is what I've found out, in case this helps someone out there:

When Market installs the free version of my app, the apk file is installed to `/data/app/com.company.app.apk`, the file content is exactly the same as I built it, same file size, same everything.

For the paid version that uses Market Vendor Licensing, the apk file itself is installed to `/data/app-private/com.company.app.apk`. This is the same file as I released. However, the resources are extracted and installed to another file `/data/app/com.company.app.zip`, note the file extension. This zip file contains only resources, so it's significantly smaller. But the .apk file in `/data/app-private` has everything, so the file size is the same as I built it.

`ApplicationInfo.publicSourceDir` always points to the file in /data/app, so it's `/data/app/com.company.app.zip` in the paid version's case, and `/data/app/com.company.app.apk` for the free version. For the paid version, I obtained the pathname from `publicSourceDir`, then replace.app with app-private, and replace .zip with .apk to get the original file.

If I install the apk directly to an emulator, then there is only one file and is always installed under /data/app.

Comment: this is very interesting, thanks for solving it.  Does it seem to be working as anti-piracy measure?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not right. The market works in the following way: you choose an application and push a button to install it. After that market sends the intent to gtalk service to install the application. This service downloads apk file that you've uploaded to the market and when finishes it installs this apk. Just during the installation can some changes happen. It seems to me that from the application during the installation classes.dex file is extracted and from this file optimized dex (.odex) is produced and put in the separate directory. That's why you see the difference in the files.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The file classes.dex is not seen in the file com.company.app-2.zip, nor is there any .odex. All I see in this ZIP file is resources.arsc, the manifest, and the res folder. Could you please tell me how can I find out where did the signature files (in META-INF folder) go? I want to compare the signature files' content with a set of known values, for anti-piracy purpose. Thank you.

Comment: I guess I'm not very helpful in this question. The package itself is signed with jarsigner and there is no actual certificate as I guess. You can read here more about signing: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html

Comment: thank you very much. Anyway, I saw some cert/signature related files in META-INF folder. What I did is during runtime, it reads through the entire apk file byte by byte to find a certain byte pattern that I know belongs in my certificate. If can't find it, this means this apk file was signed by someone else, a piracy case. This is successful in the free version. But didn't work on the paid version because the apk file has been splitted and I can't find the other part.

Comment: It can be. Certificates can be needed to install encrypted connection with the application servers so it's can be that in this folder this type of certificates are stored.